# powershell use CSV to create variables

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I am a total novice when it comes to powershell.  I would like to create a little script to save me a lot of time and after a little research, I am sure it can be achieved using Import-CSV command.

Basically I need to run a command on multiple PC's but the variable is different for each command.  I wish to pull that variable from a comparision in a CSV file.  So find current Hostname, then use that hostname to find the corresponding asset number in the CSV and then use that asset number as a variable in the final comamnd.

Looking at other examples on here, I have this so far:

```
$Asset = @()
$Host = @()

Import-Csv -Path "C:\hostnametoasset.csv" |`
ForEach-Object {
    $Asset += $_.Asset
    $Host += $_.Host
}

$Hostname = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name).Name

if ($Host -contains $Hostname)
{
C:\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /setvalue:"Asset Tracking Number","$Asset"
}
```

Section of the CSV:

```
Asset,Host
10756,PCD001
10324,PCD002
10620,PCD003
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Don't use `$Host` as a variable name (it's a built-in variable). 2. You're not using any host name in the BIOS utility configuration command, so it's not clear why you need a host name in the first place.

Comment: yes I swapped $Host to $Name and updated my CSV.  The host name is needed for comparision in the CSV to return the asset number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of different points...
Importing a CSV results in an array of objects that you can filter on.

```
$Lines = Import-Csv -Path "C:\hostnametoasset.csv"
$Line = $Lines | ?{$_.host -match $ENV:COMPUTERNAME}
```

You can then use the filter results directly by accessing the member you need.

```
C:\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /setvalue:"Asset Tracking Number","$($Line.Asset)"
```

NOTE: I cannot test this directly right now so hopefully I got the syntax right.

Comment: thanks very much.  the final script looks like this:

`$csv = Import-Csv -Path "\\lsqus009\HPSSM\BCU\hostnametoasset.csv"
$Line = $csv | ?{$_.Name -match $ENV:COMPUTERNAME}
\\lsqus009\HPSSM\BCU\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /setvalue:"Asset Tracking Number","$($Line.Asset)"`

and it works beautifully